# Detecting the SSID of WiFi connected to in MIT App Inventor?

Tags: wifi, app-inventor, ssid

Is there any extensions in MIT App Inventor 2 which can get the SSID of the WiFi network a user is connected to?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is the [WiFi Extension](https://puravidaapps.com/wifi.php) and its `SSID` block.
 That extension also offers some more useful blocks to use in a wireless LAN.

[image]